# Why won't a Delphi-XE2 64-bit windows program run from within integrated environment?

Tags: delphi, debugging, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

An attempt to debug a small and simple 64-bit Windows application in Delphi XE2 gives this runtime error message:   Unable to create process, ...

This error occurs upon an attempt to run the program with the build-configurations debug and release. It does not occur when started with the "Run without Debugging" in the project manager.

This happens only when trying to run the program from within Delphi's integrated environment.

This is on a 64 bit Desktop, with Windows 7 Professional and Delphi XE2 Update 4.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced exactly this. In my case the problem was my anti-virus  (Sophos at that time). I had to completely uninstall the AV program to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  The problem went away after I started Delphi XE2 with the intention of doing an experiment to confirm or deny that anti-virus software on the PC was (is?) responsible for the problem.  My results are inconclusive as the problem went away.  Did it go away before I closed and restarted Delphi?  I don't know.  I'll keep this problem under observation.

Comment: Might also happen when the firewall blocks the 64-bit debugger process.

Comment: I've experienced this also, and found it to be fairly random. I think there may be an intermittent bug somewhere with the Win64 Remote Debugger (remember: the debugger is a separate process as the IDE is 32-bit). Never really found the precise cause in my cases, though!

Comment: @LaKraven I had 6 machines in the office all break at once when we switched AV software. Removing the AV fixed them all.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was sharing internet connection through a wi-fi adapter. The solution is to turn sharing off